# How can I add separate ggplot titles to plots which created with facet_wrap?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I was trying to create a FOR loop to get multiple graphs with different variables. I used facet_wrap to gather them together by City in 3 different categories. First group shows gender of player, second shows which sports branch and last one shows team they are playing. What I'm aiming here is giving each facet a different ggtitle and xlab. Should I try to do this in a FOR loop again with a new vector or what?

Here is an example of my data

```
data <- structure(list(Team = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("T1", "T2", "T3"), class = "factor"), 
    Sport = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Sport1", "Sport2", "Sport3"), class = "factor"), 
    Gender = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("F", "M"), class = "factor"), City = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("City1", 
    "City2"), class = "factor"), Supporters= c(999L, 888L, 777L, 
    999L, 888L, 777L, 666L, 555L, 444L, 666L, 555L, 444L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

```
Team          Sport   Gender    City        Supporters
T1            Sport1    M       City1           999
T2            Sport1    F       City1           888
T3            Sport1    M       City1           777
T1            Sport2    M       City1           999
T2            Sport2    F       City1           888
T3            Sport2    M       City1           777
T1            Sport2    F       City2           666
T2            Sport2    M       City2           555
T3            Sport2    F       City2           444
T1            Sport3    F       City2           666
T2            Sport3    M       City2           555
T3            Sport3    F       City2           444
```

```
for(i in data[, c(1:3)]) {
  graph <- data[, sum(Supporters), by= .(i, City)]
data1 <- print (ggplot(graph,aes(x=reorder (i,-V1), V1, fill=i))+ geom_bar(stat="identity", width = 0.8, position= position_dodge(width = 0.9))+
theme_bw(base_size = 17) +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=-90,hjust=1)) +
scale_y_continuous( breaks = seq(0, 50000, by = 5000))+
facet_wrap( ~ City)+
ylab("Supporters"))
}
```

When done right it should include different ggtitles for each facet and xlab which specifies its column name. I hope I was able to express myself clearly. Can you guys help me out? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Do you need to use facet? I recommend you avoid the `for`-loops, and use `ggpubr::ggarrange` instead, as it allows for more flexibility in your case.

Comment: Yes I have to, this is for an assignment by my teacher he has specific requests.
Use data.table and facet only, create plots by ```for``` loop.

Comment: What do you want your titles to be?  Also, what are your results so far--what does your code give you now that you want to change/add?  Facets are labeled according to the levels of the factor, which are typically arranged alphabetically.  You can change the order through `levels(...)` if you want it to be different.  For the title, you have to call either `ggtitle()`, or--my preference--use `labs(title=...)`.  I would suggest using a `paste()` call to create the title character string in your loop if you want it different for each set of plots, but not sure what you want your title to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not very good with data.table, but one suggestion is to use the names of the column, instead of passing the column directly. This way you can have the grouping variable as the title. Also you can store you plots in a list:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)
library(patchwork)

data = data.table(data)
data1 = vector("list",3)
names(data1) = colnames(data)[1:3]

for(i in colnames(data)[1:3]) {

  graph <- data[,sum(Population), keyby= c(i,"Region")]
  graph[[i]] <- reorder(graph[[i]],graph[["V1"]])
  data1[[i]] <- ggplot(graph,aes_string(x=i,y="V1", fill=i))+ 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width = 0.8, position= position_dodge(width = 0.9))+
  theme_bw(base_size = 17) +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=-90,hjust=1)) +
  scale_y_continuous( breaks = seq(0, 50000, by = 5000))+
  facet_wrap( ~ Region)+
  ylab("Population*Thousand*")+
  ggtitle(i)

}
```

To see one plot:

```
print(data1[[1]]) 
#or print(data1[["Age_group"]])
```

[image]

To combine:

```
wrap_plots(data1,ncol=2)
```

[image]

Comment: In my eyes you are a god now on. Thank you for your help and explanation. It's perfect. Such a little but elegant touch :) Have a good day sire.

Comment: eerrmmm no i am human :) it's just practice everyday. I learned something about data.table today =)